# How to bind property of parent element

Tags: wpf, silverlight, binding

i have a quick Binding Question about Silverlight.
I have some Expander and want to overwrite their Header Templates

```
<Controls:Expander Header="MyHeaderTitle"
                   HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyExpanderHeaderTemplate}">
   //Content
</Controls:Expander>
<Controls:Expander Header="MyNextHeaderTitle"
                       HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource MyExpanderHeaderTemplate}">
    //Content
</Controls:Expander>
```

In the header template i have an textbox and want to bind the text to the Header of the expander.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyExpanderHeaderTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Header}">
       // some triggering stuff
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

I tried some stuff with RelativeSource (Self and TemplatedParent) but nothing seems to work.
Some Ideas would be great, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyExpanderHeaderTemplate">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding .}">
       // some triggering stuff
    </TextBlock>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor`

```
<TextBlock 
  Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource RelativeSourceMode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:Expander}}}, Path=Header"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyExpanderHeaderTemplate"> 
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the quick answers.
FindAncestor doesn't seem to work under Silverlight the Way it does in WPF (can't resolve AncestorType..)
But {Binding} or {Binding .} do the trick!